# Is $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

In the Linear Algebra book we're using (Linear Algebra with Applications, Bretscher, p.129), the author defines this as the function of the unit circle.

I understand why the equation of a circle can't be a function. In this case however, I could see how despite failing the vertical line test, $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ still outputs a unique value for any $t$ and is therefore technically a function.

Is that the rationale, or is $f(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$ not really a function despite what the author states?

Comment: It is a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$. However, there is no function from $\mathbb R$ to itself whose graph is the circle, as this would require taking on multiple output values at a single input value.

Comment: As a side comment, if you were to draw this graph, it would have to be 3D, and would look like a spiral going up (if the $t$ direction is upwards).

Comment: You don't have a "function of the unit circle," you have a parametrization of it. It is indeed a function $[0,2\pi)\to S^1$. However, the equation of a unit circle ($x^2+y^2=1$) is "not (the graph of) a function," in the sense that $y$ is not a function of $x$ (that's what we mean when we say that).

Comment: @RoyD. Could you please expand on what you said (why it would have to be 3D and would look like a spiral going up)?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff The graph of a function $f:X\to Y$ is a subset of $X\times Y$, comprised of the points $(x,f(x))$. In this case, we have $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$, so the graph is a subset of $\Bbb R^3$ which is comprised of the elements $(t,\cos t,\sin t)$, and this looks like a spiral. (Technically it's a subset of $\Bbb R\times\Bbb R^2$ comprised of the points $(t,(\cos t,\sin t))$, but this distinction is artificial.)

Comment: @blue Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just parametric equation of a circle $f(t)=\left[\begin{matrix}\cos t\\\sin t\end{matrix}\right]$ http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html, it's a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and its range is the unit circle centered at the origin.

Comment: Hi @Conifold. How could I see that the point P is moving on the circle when t increases?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Just take some values for $t$, like $\pi/6$, $\pi/4$, $\pi/3$, $\pi/2$, $2\pi/3$, $\pi$, etc., and plot the points they are mapped into. The period of sine and cosine is $2\pi$ so after that everything repeats.

Answer (score 1):

The vertical line test only works for potential functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where the graph is in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the input is on the x-axis, and the output is on the y-axis. Hence a vertical line touching more than one point corresponds to multiple outputs for one input.
For a function $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$, the graph exists in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and you can represent the inputs on the x-axis, and the outputs in the y-z plane. Here the appropriate test would be a "plane perpendicular to the x-axis test." If a plane given by $x=c$ touches the purported graph in more than one point then its not the graph of a function of x.

In your case as mentioned by @anon, the graph is a spiral around the x-axis, so any plane perpendicular to the x-axis only intersects it at one point.